# Error while Google Assistant authenticate with service and send a SYNC request

Tags: firebase, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

Hi I am trying to implement an example of below codelab, which explains how to publish a cloud service that manages a virtual smart washing machine, then build a smart home Action and connect it to the google Assistant.

https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer?hl=en#0

I am stuck in the forth step when I am adding a test washing machine in my google assistant/google home. It gives error as shown in attached pic in my phone when I am trying to add.

Can any one help me for the same.

I tried changing the User id field in my index.js file but it still persist. It would be great if someone can explain the error & reason of occurrence.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You mention the error screenshot in your question, can you attach the error you are encountering? Also you might have some additional logs regarding the error in your project, please take a look at the Search Logs section of the Troubleshooting Guide in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The codelab is meant to be used without needing any changes in the code besides what’s provided in the steps. Once you copy-paste the app.onSync(...) example in the Update SYNC response section, it should work without additional changes.